# Cannot return json from function in a nodejs app that does with a python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

I think that some asynchronous stuff is happening that I cannot figure out
Please tell how can I solve this with `async-await` if possible.

my code:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')


const getWeatherReport = (location) => {
    let dataToSend, result
    const python = spawn('python', [__dirname+'\\weathergetter.py', location.toString()])

    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
        dataToSend = JSON.parse(data.toString().replace(/\'/g, '\"'));
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    
    python.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
    })
  
    python.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    return dataToSend
    
}

var wea = getWeatherReport("kolkata")
console.log(wea)
```

> **Output**: 
> undefined
> Pipe data from python script ...
> child process close all stdio with code 0

I want the function to return a `json object` which is assigned to `dataToSend`. Here I am actually working with a python script.

the python script has no problem. When I `console.log(dataToSend)` inside `python.stdout.on()` and `python.on()` as **commented out in the code**, the json objects gets printed to the console. But I cannot **make the function return the json object**.

### Please refer to these for what I was following:

- **mainly this one** -- https://medium.com/swlh/run-python-script-from-node-js-and-send-data-to-browser-15677fcf199f
- https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pandas-in-node-js-application-47a76ae42a2a

Comment: please refer to this question -- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69703112/17123424)