# Cannot return json object from a JavaScript function in a nodejs project that deals with a python script?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

I think that some asynchronous stuff is happening that I cannot figure out
Please tell how can I solve this with `async-await` if possible.

my code:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')


const getWeatherReport = (location) => {
    let dataToSend, result
    const python = spawn('python', [__dirname+'\\weathergetter.py', location.toString()])

    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
        dataToSend = JSON.parse(data.toString().replace(/\'/g, '\"'));
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    
    python.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
    })
  
    python.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    return dataToSend
    
}

var wea = getWeatherReport("kolkata")
console.log(wea)
```

> **Output**: 
> undefined
> Pipe data from python script ...
> child process close all stdio with code 0

I want the function to return a `json object` which is assigned to `dataToSend`. Here I am actually working with a python script.

the python script has no problem. When I `console.log(dataToSend)` inside `python.stdout.on()` and `python.on()` as **commented out in the code**, the json objects gets printed to the console. But I cannot **make the function return the json object**.

### Please refer to these for what I was following:

- **mainly this one** -- https://medium.com/swlh/run-python-script-from-node-js-and-send-data-to-browser-15677fcf199f
- https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pandas-in-node-js-application-47a76ae42a2a

***NOTE: Please don't mark this question as duplicate as it was done to my last question. I can understand that there are many posts on this topic in stack overflow already. But it is not helping in my case.***

### What I tried after my previous post was closed:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')


const getWeatherReport = async (location) => {
    let dataToSend
    const python = spawn('python', [__dirname+'\\weathergetter.py', location.toString()])

    python.stdout.on('data', async (data) => {
        console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
        dataToSend = JSON.parse(data.toString().replace(/\'/g, '\"'));
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    
    python.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
    })
  
    python.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
        // console.log(dataToSend)
    })
    return  await dataToSend
    
}

var wea = await getWeatherReport("kolkata")
console.log(`data: ${ await wea}`)
```

Comment: I posted this question because --- Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t resolve your question, **ask a new one**.

Comment: If you disagree with closure as duplicate, the proper response is to [edit] your post and explain exactly what is different and why.
Asserting that it just _is_ different is not enough. See
["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/4642212)
and [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401721/4642212).

Comment: Voting to close again because exactly the same `Promise`–`resolve` approach was suggested in the linked posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not using async/await or a callback, you're returning `dataToSend` before it has had the time to be populated by the `data` callback.

If you want to use async/await, you'll need to wrap things in a `new Promise` here. It's also a good idea to gather all the output from the subprocess before decoding only at the end, since there's no guarantee all of the JSON will be delivered in a single event.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const getWeatherReport = (location) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buf = "";
    const python = spawn("python", [
      __dirname + "\\weathergetter.py",
      location.toString(),
    ]);

    python.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      buf += data;
    });

    python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    python.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        return reject(`child process died with ${code}`);
      }
      const dataToSend = JSON.parse(buf.toString().replace(/\'/g, '"'));
      return resolve(dataToSend);
    });
  });
};

async function main() {
  var wea = await getWeatherReport("kolkata");
  console.log(wea);
}
main();
```

Comment: your code is not working. 
var wea = await getWeatherReport("kolkata");
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: It does work if you have top-level await enabled, or call that from an async function.

Comment: can you see the image that i added to your answer

Comment: See my edit. As I said, you'd need to have top-level await, or use an async function. I did the latter for you.

Comment: is there any simpler way to approach this?

Comment: This is honestly as simple as I can think to make it. If you'd have multiple child processes, you can of course refactor `getWeatherReport` to e.g. `getChildProcessOutput`...

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will try `getChildProcessOutput`